# Raspberry pi connect itself to wifi by running bash script

Tags: php, linux, bash, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

We have turned our raspberry pi into an access point and put some php and html pages on it.

Our goal is to make the raspberry pi to detect the WIFI and connect itself to the WIFI.

The html page takes wifi name and password, then the php triggers bash script file to connect Raspberry Pi to wifi.

Does this plan work? Just want to confirm since we are beginner of raspberry pi.

Comment: How would the user get to the html page to enter a password _before_ connecting to the wifi?

Comment: we assigned an ip on the pi, it works like wifi router, you can go to page by typing its ip address

Comment: I see. So then you want to change the network settings after the user enters some information like SSID, password, etc.? I think it is possible. Basically you change the network settings and then restart the network interface. Probably a lot of details to work out, but the idea seems reasonable.

Answer (score -1):

That's not a good idea. You should use the wifi antenna; you can get one from sparkfun or amazon and configure it via the gui. That'll keep your raspberry pi connect automatically once it boots up to the os; then you can run any scripts or programs that requires internet connection.